# GA4 custom_dimension shows (not set) in the reports but in the Debug view of Firebase and Realtime instead shows the value

Tags: firebase, google-analytics-4

I am experiencing an issue with a GA4 custom dimension.
The custom dimension in question is "step" which was implemented in an event in my Android and IOS App.
When I debug with the Debug View/ Realtime on GA4 I see the custom dimension correctly populated, but in GA4's Standard and Explore reports I see the associated value (not set).

The custom dimension "step" has been mapped to GA4.
Could you please help me with this?

From the reports I see that in the past the custom dimension "step" collected the correct values, but from a certain build app onwards, the custom dimension started to populate as "not set". How is this possible if in the Realt times I see the values?

[step parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ikjda.png)

Thanks